# How to keep the checkboxes selected during datalist while moving next, previous page?

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I have Code Igniter based list the data from database with paging, search and sorting ..  I have checkboxes too for each record. When I check multiple with different pages, I need those selected values to process for another page. How can I get it those?

At present, when I move one page to another, the selected check boxes values are gone.. How to retain to get finally?

Comment: When you change page, are the values already inserted into the database, or do you need to be able to select a number of checkboxes accross multiple pages before inserting the list back to the database?

Comment: before insert to db, i need to keep the selected check boxes across the pages

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the set_checkbox()? try it out.

check it out in the [codeigniter documentetion](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: i need to retain the checked values on multiple pages and finally want to store to database ..

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox values are relatively small, you could use sessions, e.g.

In your controller:

```
if (!$this->session->flashdata('checkbox_field'))
{
    $data['checkbox_field'] = $this->post->input('checkbox_field');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('checkbox_field', $data['checkbox_field']);
}
```

In your view (can be all on one line, just indented so you don't have to scroll to see whole string):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_field" 
id="checkbox_field"<?php 
echo set_checkbox('checkbox_field', '1', $checkbox_field); ?> value="1" />
```

Comment: @logudotcom -- Have you had a chance to test it out yet, and is it working for you?

Comment: i will do this evening ...sorry guys